# How to get all combination of many array?

Tags: c#, c, arrays

Edit:
I have building in which there are windows,walls, doors,and etc. I want to make combinations between them by taking a door from doors , window from windows and so on. the combination should include all the possibility. I present the problem as set of array and each array has set of elements. Now I want to combine those element together under the condition that each combination have to include at most one elements of each array (the number of array is unlimited and could be any number).To clarify the problem,I give an example:

Example arrays:

```
array1={1,2,3}
array2={a,b,c}
array3={#,$,%}
```

Output:

```
1
1,a
1,a,#
1,a,$
1,a,%
1,b
1,b,#
1,b,$
1,b,%
1,c
1,c,#
1,c,$
1,c,%
(for 2 and 3 the same)
a
a,#
a,$
a,%
b
b,#
b,$
b,%
(for c the same)
#
$
%
```

That means in each combination at most one element from each array.

Comment: Check out this blog series by Eric Lippert [Computing a Cartesian product with LINQ](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).  It's similar to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var array1 = new[] {1, 2, 3};
        var array2 = new[] { "a", "b", "c"};
        var array3 = new[] { "#", "$", "%"};
        // ----------------------------------
```

Doing it yourself...

```
        var l1 = array1.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToList();
        var l2 = array2.ToList();
        var l3 = array3.ToList();
        l1.Add("");
        l2.Add("");
        l3.Add("");
        // ----------------------------------
        foreach (var a in l1)
            foreach (var b in l2)
               foreach (var c in l3)
         Console.WriteLine($"{a}{b}{c}");
```

or, using LINQ

```
        var result =
            from x in l1
            from y in l2
            from z in l3
            select new[] { x, y, z };
        foreach (var r in result)
            Console.WriteLine($"{r[0]}{r[1]}{r[2]}");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, For limited number of arrays, your solution is ok but for unlimited number of array, it does not work( I don't know how many array I have